# Update OpenGL version to 4.6 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I have problem related my nvidia driver in Ubuntu 18.04. Actually the problem occurred in computer server and I remote the computer server by using X2Go.

My Computer Server using Ubuntu 18.04 And using NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1080 TI

I am using the method to install Nvidia Drivers from this: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

And actually it installed the latest driver as I am check using nvidia-smi: wheras showing I am using driver **440.26** which means the latest driver and my Mesa Version is **19.3**.

But when I check my openGL using glxinfo | grep ':' it showing that my openGL version is **3.1** which is not latest update. I really need to upgrade my openGL version to **4.6**.
Here, is my OpenGL version

> OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 19.3.0-devel (git-ff6e148 2019-10-29 bionic-oibaf-ppa)

I am struggle for hours to do this but I can't. Could someone tell me how to proceed please?

Thank you to help me.

Comment: I install `inxi` and run `inxi -G`  What does it show?

Comment: It shows

Graphics:  Card-1: NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
           Card-2: NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
           Card-3: ASPEED ASPEED Graphics Family
           Card-4: NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
           Card-5: NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
           Display Server: X.Org 7.0.0
           drivers: nvidia,nvidia,ast,nvidia,nvidia
           Resolution: 1920x1052@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.0, 256 bits)
           version: 3.1 Mesa 19.3.0-devel (git-ff6e148 2019-10-29 bionic-oibaf-ppa)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any requested additional details, and use block quotes (triple back-tics on lines before and after quoted block) for console output.

Comment: Also, please include the output of `glxinfo | grep "core profile"` instead. You should see something like `OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8` for example.

Comment: Also, if you are using remote display with x2go, you will almost certainly be limited to software rendering (`llvmpipe` renderer in this case), which will not render on the hardware.

Comment: Also, your card only supports OpenGL 4.5 according to the NVidia web site.

Comment: Hello dobey, thank you for your reply, I just edit my Question. and showing my OpenGL version. So, do you mean the main problem is x2go itself? Basically I need to update at least 4.3.0

Comment: Yes, the problem is that x2go is an X server not running on the hardware you are wanting to render things on. You can't "update" GL version as such. It might help though if you explained better in your question what exactly you're trying to do by running things on the server. If you're trying to play games remotely, that will be problematic. But if you're trying to do ML/CUDA stuff, then the Xorg stuff is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: Actually I want to run car simulator (CARLA) for my research, Ok then, I will try to access the server directly. Thank you so much.