# Install OpenGL 4.6 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, opengl, nvidia-geforce, mesa

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with the nouveau video driver. For some reason, the video driver is using OpenGL 4.3 instead of 4.6:

```
inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: nouveau 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: NV136 v: 4.3 Mesa 20.0.8
```

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:136 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

How do I upgrade OpenGL to 4.6?

Comment: I did find the following similar question without an answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186147/update-opengl-version-to-4-6-in-ubuntu-18-04