# can't update openGL to 4.6 on 20.04 with intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics

Tags: updates, graphics, intel, opengl

I am using **20.04.4 LTS** and for my study course i must install **openGL 4.6** but i am stuck at version 4.2 and cannot update it.

glxinfo | grep -i version:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Version: 22.0.0
    Max core profile version: 4.2
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.2 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.0 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.20
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 22.0.0 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 22.0.0 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

inxi -G:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: i915 resolution: 1600x900~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) 
  v: 4.2 Mesa 22.0.0 - kisak-mesa PPA
```

I installed the packages **libgl1-mesa-dev** and **mesa-common-dev**.
I think this person [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269960/install-opengl-4-6-on-ubuntu-20-04) got the same issue but there is no solution. Is my GPU too old? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am afraid that your GPU is indeed to old. See also here: https://superuser.com/questions/561177/which-version-of-opengl-does-intels-integrated-graphics-card-support and here https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html